# Disable a specific form control button from running its assigned macro even if it is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, button

I would like to be able to prevent a specific button ("Button 4925") from running its assigned macro even when it is clicked. Basically, when you click it, it would either do nothing or show a message that says " This is an essential item that cannot be deleted" 
In other words, I would like to be able to exit the sub only if the clicked button is in cell A12. Otherwise, run the code as normal. I don't know how to do that considering that I am a very beginner in VBA.
Some information:
The button is a form control button. Not an Active X one. It gets copied and pasted by another macro on the sheet. The assigned macro is written under a Standard Module.
The assigned macro function is to delete a relative range of rows. Here is the code:

```
    Sub Delete_Button()

' Delete_Button Macro

' Step 1: Select the cell under the clicked button
Dim r As Range
Dim s As Object
Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
r.Select

' Step 2: delete all buttons relative to the selected cell from step 1
StartCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0).Address
EndCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Address

For Each s In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
If Not Intersect(Range(StartCell, EndCell), s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s

' Step 3: delete the rows relative to the selected cell from step 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0).Rows("1:9").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must 'tell' to the code, in a way, that it must not delete the range.

So, I would suggest you to create a `Private` variable on top of the module keeping the button code (in the declarations area):

```
 Private stopButCode As Boolean
```

Than, you must make this variable `True`. Use a Check box, or a piece of code in another control to make it `True`.

The Button code must be adapted in a way like following:

```
If Not stopButCode Then
   'delete whatever is to be deleted
Else
   MsgBox "Deletion not allowed..."
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Edited:
If you want the code not working only if the button will be on cell "A12", you can use adapt your code as following:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As Object
Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
If r.Address = "$A$12" then Exit Sub

'here follows your existing code...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am very basic in VBA and I am not sure how to use the private variable thing.

Comment: @Vigo: You simple write `Private stopButCode As Boolean` on top of the  module where the button code exists.

Comment: @Vigo: But if you want to exit the code only for the case when the button is on cell A12, you have only to insert a code line `If r.Address = "$A$12" then Exit Sub`, as you can see in my edited last piece of code...

Comment: Amazing. It worked! Thank you so much. I can't believe it was that simple.